# What is a concise easy to read way of testing to see if two numbers out of three are equal?

Tags: algorithm

Basically, if I have a function like so:

```
function foo (int a, int b, int c) {
    return true if two out of the three variables are true otherwise false
}
```

Is there a simple and concise way to find out if there are n numbers are equal out of a set? What about only three items? Is there a mathematical operation that I can take advantage of? I know that I can do an iterative approach to solve, I'm just curious if there are other ways to solve that are clearer.

Here is a break down of conditions because I'm having a hard time expressing the problem:

```
if no numbers are equal, return false
if two numbers out of three are equal, return true
if all three numbers are equal, return false
```

Comment: If all three are equal, you want to return true?

Comment: Insert the numbers into a set. If the size of the set is smaller than the number of inputs, at least two were equal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One method would be to add the parameters to a set and then see if the length of that set is equal to 2 (or less than 3 if you it to return true if they are all equal as well).  For example, in Python:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    return len(set((a, b, c))) == 2
```

Comment: Programmer time is worth more than CPU time, if code speed was all that mattered languages like Python wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you're going to get any more efficient or concise than the manual way:

```
if a == b 
   return b != c 
else
   return b == c || a == c
```

Or else this:

```
return ((a == b) || (a==c) || (b==c)) && ((a!=b) || (a!=c) || (b!=c))
```

If a, b, and c are boolean only (0 or 1) values, then you can just do this:

```
return a+b+c == 1 || a+b+c == 2 // Either two are false, or two are true
```

Answer (score 3):

In C or C++ you can do:

```
return ((a==b)|(b==c)|(a==c));
```

or to return the number of matches:

```
return ((a==b)+(b==c)+(a==c));
```

For the case where you only want to indicate if 2 are equal:

```
return (((a==b)+(b==c)+(a==c)) == 1);
```

We like to use bit-wise or | rather than logical || for performance. This is all based on the standard indicating that comparisons return 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.

Comment: You third example will return true if all three are equal.  It should be `return (((a==b)+(b==c)+(a==c)) == 1);`

Answer (score 2):

if the input variables are boolean, than you could build a truth table and minimize the resulting function for instance with a KV-diagram

```
a b c f(a,b,c)
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

The minimization yields to return the result of

```
  (c and a) or (b and a) or (c and b)
```

KV-Diagram are easy to handle for up to 4 variables (with experience maybe 6 variables) more booleans need more sophisticated techniques.

Comment: Except that for the case of all 3 being true then the function is supposed to return false

Comment: yep, you're right. He wanted numbers anyway, so this would be right as useful as wrong ;(

Answer (score 2):

In C, you could use

```
return ((a == b) || (b == c)) ^ (a == c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int difference = a-(b-c);
if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0)
  return false;
if((difference == a) /*b=c*/ || (difference == c) /*a=b*/ || (difference == (2*a-b)) /*a=c*/)
  return true;
return false;
```